# Map a text file to key/value pair in order to group them in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a  spark dataframe in pyspark from a text file, that has different number of rows and columns and map it to key/value pair, the key is the first 4 characters from the first column of the text file.  I want to do that in order to remove the redundant rows and to be able  group them later by the key value.  I know how to do that on pandas but still confused where to start doing that in pyspark.

My input is a text file that has the following:

```
  1234567,micheal,male,usa
  891011,sara,femal,germany
```

I want to be able to group every row by the first six characters in the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column that contains only the first six characters of the first column, and then group by that:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df2 = df.withColumn("key", col("first_col")[:6])
df2.groupBy("key").agg(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I would like to know if possible to use instead of .agg  since I want to show the rest of the columns without performig any operations such as sum,count....etc

Comment: gr = df2.groupBy("key").agg(countDistinct("key")).  For example this will give me the distinct values is there anyway to show the rest of the columns assigned with this key ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You'd like to see all of the rows associated with each unique key value?

Comment: yes , I didnt using join but is there any other way ? I am still new to pyspark thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Grouping requires an aggregate function. If you want to see all of the items by value, why not just sort by the `key` column (with `df2.sort("key").show()`)?

Comment: Perfect, yes this is what I am looking for.  Thanks a lot :)